# How does http "multipart/x-gzip" work?

Tags: header, gzip

I have been struggling to figure out the a "multipart/x-gzip" would work?

If a sender tends to send a multipart Gzipped file to a recipient, will the data be first zipped, partitioned and then put together and inflated(uncompressed) at the recipient? or is the data first partitioned then zipped and then sent to the recipient? Where with each partition uncompress-ion is done and then real data is put together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google your answer my friend :

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

nice video that explain it on google code:
http://code.google.com/speed/articles/gzip.html